# Is it possible to get recent checkins at a venue with the Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

THe checkins/recent endpoint only returns friends of the authorized users. I'm wondering if there's any way to get recent checkins at a specific venue for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally not allowed for privacy concerns. If you are building an app for venue managers though, you can subscribe to the [venue push API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime), and your users will see check-ins to venues they manage.